# CentOS: I can't install crontab

Tags: linux, centos

I need install crond service and I'm not able to do this.
Where could be the problem? Please help.

```
sudo yum install vixie-cron crontabs
```

...

```
Downloading Packages:
(1/2): crontabs-1.10-11.el5.noarch.rpm                   | 7.0 kB     00:00
(2/2): vixie-cron-4.1-81.el5.x86_64.rpm                  |  83 kB     00:00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                           1.7 MB/s |  90 kB     00:00
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Finished Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing     : vixie-cron                                               1/3
Error unpacking rpm package 4:vixie-cron-4.1-81.el5.x86_64
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /etc/cron.d: cpio: mkdir
  Updating       : crontabs                                                 2/3
Error unpacking rpm package crontabs-1.10-11.el5.noarch
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /etc/crontab;51dc6ae1: cpio: open

Failed:
  crontabs.noarch 0:1.10-11.el5          vixie-cron.x86_64 4:4.1-81.el5

Complete!
root@serverx:~# /sbin/chkconfig crond on
error reading information on service crond: No such file or directory
```